# best way to append sql query string in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a query string with mandatory fields like

```
const sqlString = `select * from users where name=${user.name} AND age=${user.age} AND location=${user.location}`;
```

I may also get optional fields based on the user input if entered.So I am appending it like

```
if (user.mobile) {
    sqlString += `AND phone=${user.mobile}`
}
if (user.email) {
    sqlString += `AND emailId=${user.email}`
}
if (user.street) {
    sqlString += `AND LOWER(street) LIKE '%${user.street.toLowerCase()}%'`
}
if (user.pincode) {
    sqlString += `AND pincode=${user.pincode} `
}
if (user.height) {
    sqlString += `AND height=${user.height}`
}
```

How can I optimize the code and make it compact and readable?

Comment: Note: If this these data are determined by the user, then your code is vulnarable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements instead of string concatenation.

Comment: I would like to share an old developers adage with you -> "If it aint broke, don't fix it"

Comment: Absolutely, positively, **NOT THIS WAY**. Use prepared statements with placeholder values.

Comment: @trincot okay. Is there a way to avoid multiple if statments?

Comment: Tip: Use a database layer like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#applying-where-clauses) which makes adding arbitrary `WHERE` clauses like this as easy as adding properties to an object. It could be as easy as `let conds = { }` and then `if (user.email) { conds.email = user.email }`.

Comment: @tadman yes, query will be rewritten with prepared statements . Is there a better approch for multiple if statments in js?

Comment: First convert your code to use prepared statements, as that will look quite different, and then see how you would code the "dynamic" part.

Comment: The better approach is to use Sequelize. The next best approach is to organize your query conditions into an array, and append placeholder values to another array at the same time, like `let conds = [ ]; let values = [ ];` and then `if (user.email) { conds.push('email=?'); values.push(user.email); }` so later you can do `WHERE ${conds.join(' AND ')}`.

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend using Sequelize as it will not only make your life a lot easier. The query composer can handle things like `IN (...)` and `IS NULL` automatically. It's also fully Promise enabled which makes using it very pleasant.

Comment: @tadman I am using athena glue db, So I am querying with  AWS athena  service, So I need to figure out if Sequelize can be possible here.

Comment: If it's MySQL-compatible then the answer is probably yes. If not then the Sequelize team probably wants to know about it.